# Can a gunk-filled vacuum pocket prevent proper draining in a top-loading GE washer?

Tags: washing-machine

My 12 year old top-loading GE washer ([GCWN5050M1WS](https://www.geapplianceparts.com/store/parts/assembly/GCWN5050M1WS)) started to get stuck in the middle of a cycle with soapy water not being drained - every once in  a while (~1 in 4 runs).  I did not notice any specific pattern (load size, water temperature, etc).  Usually after some wait switching an explicit drain mode did pump the water out, and next time it would work ok for some time.  But then the issue would come back.  After 3 or 4 incidents I figured that it was time to take a look inside - it needed a good cleaning anyway.

I removed front and top panels with controls, got the pump out, but did not find any obstruction in the hoses.  Pump is obviously working, because the issue is sporadic.  There are no kinks in the drain hose (or any others), it has not been moved (the washer stays put in one spot).

The plastic tub and stainless steel drum had visible dirt, so I decided to go really deep:  remove the drum and clean everything really good.  Instead of undoing the hub nut (after reading stories on how it took inhuman efforts, and even more to tighten it back properly) I decided to separate the drum from the hub by removing 8 Torx bolts.  Once the drum was out I had a clear view of the plastic tub.  On the left side there is a ~1cm opening that leads to a small outside pocket, on top of it a hose connects it to a "vacuum sensor".  Being fairly thin and with internal ridges this pocket was filled with dirt - you can see the photos Before and After cleaning.

Since I didn't find any obstructions in the draining, my first question:  **is it possible that the issue was caused by this gunk accumulated in "vacuum" pocket, resulting in false readings sent to the mainboard?**  Last time the drain started when I shook the drum vigorously enough, possibly fluctuating the water level against that pocket.  I do not fully understand the functionality of this vacuum pocket and sensor here - an explanation would be appreciated.

Here're the photos.  Front and Top panels removed:[image: 2]
Drum removed, Tub open wide:[image: 3]
Tub cleaned up (vacuum pocket in lower left corner):[image: 4]
Vacuum pocket (view from inside the tub) - Before cleaning:[image: 5]
Vacuum pocket (view from outside) - After cleaning:[image: 6]

(Edited to make photo titles visible)

Comment: I do not know if it would be the cause, you find out if the washer works right from now on.  Build up of gunk is probably the cause of 50% of problems in machines, the other 50% is wear and broken parts(my guess).

Comment: Thank you for the thought! I'm inclined to agree with your experience. Got more follow up Qs to post before starting assembly back, hoping that this was indeed the culprit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, for someone in a similar situation, since I have accumulated enough statistics to confirm.
**No, gunk** probably did not help, but **was not the main problem**.  Upon assembly the machine behaved properly for some time but then began to get halted again.

**The root cause turned out to be the pump motor overheating**.  Once I replaced it, the washing cycle stopped being interrupted.  My conclusion is that when the coils get too hot, the little device called *3MP Motor Protector* (placed inside a plastic sleeve next to the coils) breaks the circuit effectively shutting off the pump motor - until it cools down.  For some reason the cooling period on the original motor became longer than the wait time acceptable by the mainboard - so it would cancel the rest of the wash-cycle.

I ordered a couple of replacements from different sellers - to make sure the new one would fit.  When they arrived I checked resistance of the windings, it was very similar on all three.  However, observed temperature was reaching 70"C or more on the original Hanning (and that's only the plastic housing's temp!), but only up to 50"C on a new one.  Can't explain that (*but this should be its own new question :)*).

The picked new one (left) looks similar and claims to be an exact OEM replacement, but differs as pictured.  More power, new impeller and inlet-outlet housing design should work better than original (right).
So far so good!

[image: labels]
[image: impellers]
[image: coil windings]
[image: inlet-outlet housings]
[image: new motor max temp]