# Why a plastic ring on top of GE washer drum is filled with water?

Tags: washing-machine

Continuing the story of a top-loading [GE washer](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/277912/) cleaning, my next question is about the drum.  While lifting it from the machine encasing I heard a .. *sloshing sound of what felt like a half-gallon of water in a closed volume!*  Scared me enough, but surprisingly not a drop fell on the floor..  How come?  Well, I got the drum to the bathtub (still hearing the water sloshing), cleaned the outside.  Now it was obvious, that water can only reside in the big white plastic "ring", housed on top of the drum.  8 screws later this ring was off.

My thought was that water got inside during the 12 year life of the washer.  But I found no openings on it!  It is sealed shut.  It is fairly heavy (~6 lbs) - because of the water inside.  It reminds me of bottom ballasts of torch lamps (but these are usually black).  It is not transparent, but shining light through it gives a clue on internal structure.  It is big, so some support ridges and bulkheads are in order, but the resultant compartments apparently are not sealed off completely - turn the ring and you'll hear (and see - with a strong light source) the water inside flowing into the lower ones.

I'm failing to see a design reason to have additional weight positioned on top of the drum, especially filled with fluid - this will wreak havoc on balance when spin-drying.  Am I on the right track here?

The question:
**Why is there water inside this top ring?  How did it get there?  Is it by design?**
**If I should drain it - how to do it best?**  (Drill a hole, obviously, on the outside rim, drain and then seal it back?)

Photos.  Drum with the plastic ring on top, just taken out:[image: 2]
Drum, partially cleaned (right side) - upside down:[image: 3]
Plastic ring, partially filled with water:[image: 4]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's a **dynamic balancer**, almost certainly (but only almost as I haven't bothered to go to the parts diagram.)

Used to be able to buy one for the fan on your V8 (perhaps you still can, I don't know.)

Comment: i.e. the water moves in the plastic ring to balance the load you've got in the machine this time. It's like a wheel weight on your car's wheel that could move in the winter to balance out the random snow that packs into the rim.

Comment: Wow! Diagrams that I could find only mention "Basket Assembly WH45X10060", but do not separate the "drum" from the "ring". Interesting, makes sense. Thank you very much! Was about to drill a hole :)).

Comment: Indeed: https://www.ebay.com/itm/354939401104 "Balance ring WH45X152 fits around the top of the washer basket and is filled with fluid. It acts as a counterweight to keep the spin basket balanced as it agitates and spins."