# How to clean the corrosion off the Al-alloy hub of a GE washer without damaging it?

Tags: washing-machine

Continuing the story of a top-loading [GE washer](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/277912/) cleaning, my next question is about the hub.

I was surprised a bit about the condition of the hub under the stainless steel drum edge - see photos.  The top of the hub's cone is exposed to the same environment, yet there is no corrosion on it.  Even more surprising was to see the side edge of the hub corroded in the same manner (on the top it only happens in spots, covered by the drum).  Reckon, clothes touching the cone during washing brushes off any residue, thus the cone portion is always "polished"?

It was fairly simple to clean up the steel of the drum with solvents and plastic "knife".  I don't know the exact material of the hub, I'm guessing it is some Aluminium alloy.  I don't want to use a steel brush in order not to scratch the surface and open up new places for corrosion to start.

Question is:  **how to clean the corrosion off the hub without damaging it?**

Photos.  Hub exposed (not cleaned yet):[image: 2]
Close up of the corrosion:[image: 3]
Another close up:[image: 4]
Drum - Before cleaning:[image: 5]
Close up of the drum:[image: 6]
Drum - After cleaning[image: 7]

Comment: Why do you need to clean off the corrosion? Surely the hub is not a bearing, right? If you want to arrest the corrosion, put some silicone grease on it and bolt it back together.

Comment: Or was there some teflon or other low friction polymeric material on top of this aluminum?

Comment: Thank you @JimStewart! Isn't corrosion bad on its own? At a minimum it adds crap into washing water. Reckon, silicon grease will possibly stay in between hub and drum, but not on the outside of the hub - will wash out.
As for was it some kind of "insulator /separator" material, I don't believe so.

Comment: I did not know that this aluminum was in contact with the wash water. If it is, then you cannot coat it with any grease.

Comment: Good thought indeed! Yes, the whole hub is in the water.

Comment: Wire wheel/brush?

Comment: I'm afraid that using wire brush will scratch the surface, resulting in open cuts into aluminium alloy, promoting further /new corrosion. So will try smth less abrasive.